# Getting Error ORA-00902 - Invalid Identifier when creating a foreign key

Tags: oracle

I'm using the following script to create tables:

```
DROP TABLE Vehicle_type;
CREATE TABLE Vehicle_type
(
Vehicle_type_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
Model VARCHAR2(15),
Make VARCHAR2(15)
);

DROP TABLE Vehicle;
CREATE TABLE Vehicle
(
Registration VARCHAR2(7) PRIMARY KEY,
FOREIGN KEY (Vehicle_type_id) REFERENCES Vehicle_type(Vehicle_type_id),
GVW INT,
Year INT,
Body VARCHAR2(15)
);
```

Which creates the Vehicle_type table just fine, but when it gets to the foreign key in the Vehicle table I get the error `ORA-00904: "VEHICLE_TYPE_ID": invalid identifier`.

It's like the Vehicle_type_id column doesn't exist, but it definitely does because it shows up in SQLDeveloper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is off. You need to actually define the column that has the constraint on it, and add the constraint at the end.

```
CREATE TABLE Vehicle
(
  Registration VARCHAR2(7) PRIMARY KEY,
  Vehicle_type_id INT,                      -- add this
  GVW INT,
  Year INT,
  Body VARCHAR2(15),
  CONSTRAINT vehicle_type_fk                -- constraint name
    FOREIGN KEY (Vehicle_type_id)           -- constrained column
    REFERENCES Vehicle_type(Vehicle_type_id)
);
```

Also you'll need to drop the `vehicle` table before the `vehicle_type` table, otherwise you'll get a dependency error:

```
ORA-02449: unique/primary keys in table referenced by foreign keys
```